# Ubuntu Server with Apache domain management

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server

I'm currently trying to set my Apache configuration on ubuntu server. I have one IP(ex: 34.228.1xx.xx) and one domain(ex: mydomain.com).
I succeed to connect "Apache2 Ubuntu Default page" using IP 34.228.1xx.xx
Then I added `34.228.1xx.xx mydomain.com` in hosts file(/etc/hosts) and restarted apache using this command `sudo service apache2 restart`

But I can't see "Apache2 Ubuntu Default page" using domain mydomain.com, but  I still can connect it using IP 34.228.1xx.xx

This is my first web hosting I know my question is messed.
Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0 is not a port, it's an IP. And it is a special one which shouldn't go to /etc/hosts. Remove it.

To access Apache on the local machine (on the same on which Apache is running), use "127.0.0.1" or "localhost" as host name in your browser.

On all other machines, use either the machine's IP or its DNS name.

Of course, you have to ensure that the DNS name is pointing to the right IP. This should be a public IP (**not** something like 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x etc.) If you haven't done so already, you must register this name with your DNS hosting provider as a DNS "A" record.

Additional points to consider:

- Firewall on Apache machine must be open for incoming traffic on ports tcp/80 and/or tcp/443
- If your server is behind NAT, there must be a "forwarding" rule on the NAT machine

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. I've edited. And I'm sure DNS name is pointing to the right IP.